# Display profile picture based on ID

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

1. Users register and all data is in the collection "users" (meteor useraccounts).
2. In the profile page a user can upload a profile picture (meteor-files). The picture metadata is registered in the collection 'images'.

Everyone is allowed to browse the profiles and it works very well except i need to dynamically change the src link for the profile picture on each card displaying. I'm not sure how to go about this when the information i need is in another collection.

images collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "LT6aCTFkbRn6AAKBg",
    "size" : 1467914,
    "type" : "image/jpeg",
    "name" : "profil.jpg",
    "meta" : {},
    "ext" : "jpg",
    "extension" : "jpg",
    "extensionWithDot" : ".jpg",
    "mime" : "image/jpeg",
    "mime-type" : "image/jpeg",
    "userId" : "3JAt887HkSooRRPk2",
    "path" : "assets\\app\\uploads\\images\\LT6aCTFkbRn6AAKBg.jpg",
    "versions" : {
        "original" : {
            "path" : "assets\\app\\uploads\\images\\LT6aCTFkbRn6AAKBg.jpg",
            "size" : 1467914,
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "extension" : "jpg"
        }
    },
    "_downloadRoute" : "/cdn/storage",
    "_collectionName" : "images",
    "isVideo" : false,
    "isAudio" : false,
    "isImage" : true,
    "isText" : false,
    "isJSON" : false,
    "isPDF" : false,
    "_storagePath" : "assets\\app\\uploads\\images",
    "public" : false
}
```

The _id (LT6aCTFkbRn6AAKBg) is not the userId.

```
Template.profileDetails.helpers({
   user: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },

  PSEUDO:
  imageLinkForThisUser: function() {
    return Images.find('document in collection which has same userId key in it and return path');
  },
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.userId()` will return the current `_id` of the user if he is logged in.

So your mongo query should be:

```
Images.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()})['path'];
```

You can use findOne instead of find as (I assume) that there will be only one image per user stored.

Your **helper** function will be:

```
Template.profileDetails.helpers({
   ...
   imageLinkForThisUser: function() {
    return Images.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()})['path'];
  },
  ...
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src={{imageLinkForThisUser}} />
```

**Side tip:** You don't need to have a helper that returns the userid / user data. You may directly use handlebars to retrieve the same.

```
Eg. {{currentUser.username}}
```

More on that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311704/1745073) answer

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do get the value im looking for, but only for this user. In my HTML template i have {{#each user}}. So i need to get the Image link for each card displaying users.

Comment: imageLink: function() {
    return Images.findOne({userId: this._id})['_id'];
  }

This what i was looking for. I forgot "this" was in the context of {{#each user}}. Thank you!